# reduce accuracy of long small numbers in scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, rounding, scientific-notation

for float values in python/pandas like:
3.848326e-15

in scientific notation, How can I reduce the accuracy to display:
3.85e-15

i.e. round to 2 digits (besides the scientific notation suffix)

A regular `df['value'].round(2)` is rounding all the values to 0 - which is not what I want.

Comment: What is it you want? just to _display_ `3.85e-15` but keeping the intrinsic real value (3.848326e-15) or to really just "round" that to `3.85e-15`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
'{:0.2e}'.format(3.848326e-15)
```

results in :

```
'3.85e-15'
```

A workaround to get float:

```
float('{:0.2e}'.format(3.848326e-15).strip("'"))
```

results in :

```
3.85e-15
```

Comment: Well, the result is a string and may not be what OP wants

Comment: If your template contains only a single placeholder and nothing else, it's often easier to discard the template and use the `format` built-in _function_ directly instead: `format(3.848326e-15, ".2e")`. (It's likely to be faster, too, not that that should usually be a primary concern.)